# Multilevel model with crossed random effects?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model

I'm trying to figure out to "best" specify a model in `lmer`. Any insight is appreciated!

For background information, my data are repeated measures of some outcome `y` across a 10 year period, with each year being indexed by the variable `year`. The units of analysis are census tracts (`tract`). Each census tract is situated within several higher-order geographic factors [i.e., tracts are located in metropolitan areas (`cbsa`); states (`state`); and Census regions (`region`)]. Overall, I'm interested in estimating how `y` changes across `year`.

Most of the geographic factors are clearly delineated. E.g, over the course of the study, `tract == A123` *only* belongs to `cbsa == 1`, `state == 2` and `region == 3`. Given that structure, my first stab at a model was:

`lmer(y ~ year + (year | tract) + (1 | cbsa) + (1 | state) + (1 | region), ...)`

After taking a closer look at the data, I found that a handful of metropolitan areas were split across states. E.g., `cbsa == 1` crosses state lines and can be found in `state == 2` for some tracts  and `state == 3` for other tracts.

**My question is: is the model presented above still appropriate for how these data are structured?**

An alternative fit that I can imagine is something like:

`y ~ year + (year| region:state:cbsa:tract) + (1 | region:state:cbsa) + (1 | region:state) + (1 | region), ...`

which, to the best of my understanding, estimates separate intercepts for each state:cbsa pair (such that metropolitan areas split across states will have different random effect estimates). This and the prior model give different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description, this is a partially crossed design.

The 2nd model is appropriate for a design that is fully nested. The first model is appropriate for a partially nested design, provided that the factors are coded uniquely. For example, if you have `tract1` in `cbsa1` and you also have a `tract1` in `cbsa2`, but these are actually different tracts, then you will need to recode the tracts to be unique. More information on this can be found here:

[Crossed vs nested random effects: how do they differ and how are they specified correctly in lme4?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified/228814#228814)

Comment: Model 1 it is! This is really helpful.